# Как уменьшить размер индексов и таблицы wp_options?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Конвертирую бд Joomla ~ 6ГБ в WP с помощью плагина FG Joomla. Всего около 165000 записей. Однако уже на примерно 22000 объем wp_options.ibd составляет 11 Гб, 2 пара файлов fts*index.ibd по 1,2 Гб, хотя wp_posts — 900 Мб. В результате очень быстро заканчивается свободное место.
Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ни как, данные не могут начать занимать меньше места. Разве что удалить часть данных.

Comment: В джумле 165000 записей включая индексы занимают 6,5 гб, в wp - 22000 записей - 16 Гб. Индексы занимают больше данных. Как такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Легко. Структура БД такова, что требуется больше индексов, например. Может у них много колонок и на каждую отдельный индекс. Слово "оптимизация" (любая, хоть по скорости, хоть по объему) и "универсальный движок" не совместимы в принципе. Как разработчики сделали, так сделали. И ничего в этом не изменить. Только переписать все без использования таких монстрообразных движков и самому контролировать свои данные

Comment: Проблема оказалась в полнотекстовых индексах для wp_posts удалил их, размер перестал расти бешеными темпами.

Comment: Но проблема с wp_options осталась. Все равно растет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил отключением почти всех плагинов. Видимо какой-то из них в процессе конвертации еще и обрабатывал данные.